# Is there a limit to the number of times you can move a file with Document ID to different folders on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-id

Asking for help from anyone who happens to know if there's a limit to the number of times you can move a file with Document ID to different folders in SPO? I'm currently exploring the Document ID functionality because I need links that can be retained even when a file has been moved from one folder to another. However, I've noticed that the link with the Document ID breaks if I move the same file for the third time to a different folder. There's no issues when we speak of office documents, but this happens when the file is an image (ex: png, jpg) or even in pdf format.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good question to troubleshoot something new, however, actually it should not break the document link, I think it could be some other reasons. Even it does not break while we move the document from one site collection to another site collection. Moreover, document id feature works based on any files not on particular file types - so, I think you can raise a ticket to Microsoft describing this scenario.

Let's say, both the site collection has the document ID feature enabled.

Site Collection 1: Document ID -> DOC001
Site Collection 2: Document ID -> DOC002

Now, after moving the document from site collection 1 to site collection 2, generally, we will think the **Document ID** field will be overridden by the **DOC002** since site collection 2 has its own document ID but it is not true, still, it carries document id from site collection 1 i.e. **DOC001**

For details about moving the files with document id, refer to the below article:

[SharePoint – Moving a Document with a Document ID to Another Site Collection](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/sharepoint-moving-a-document-with-a-document-id-to-another-site-collection/)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I was able to check back with the file i moved in just an hour and I found the link working. I figured it took a while before the original file path updated so that the Document ID link could work again. With this, would you happen to know if its possible to speed up the process for the refreshing of the link? It takes about 30 minutes to an hour to get the Document ID link working again when I move a file to a folder within a folder (in the same site collection).

Comment: Hi - I have answered for the slow Document ID update issue in your other question.